# same sql query works using phpmyadmin but does not work using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I entered the following sql query in phpmyadmin, it successfully inserted a new record.

```sql
INSERT INTO `table` (id, timestamp) VALUES (1, '2013-09-18 13:00')
```

However, when I try to use it using php.

```php
//...connection
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (id, timestamp) VALUES (1, '2013-09-18 13:00')";      
$result = mysql_query($query, $cms2013) or die("error:".mysql_error());
```

It throws error like this:

> error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '13:00)' at line...

Can someone provide me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: Looks fine to me... Did you tripple check the type of quoting characters you are using? It often happens that one confuses those depending on the console font in use...

Comment: Oh, and: the ols `mysql` extension is depreciated. Use the better `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: You first use echo $query; and then what query it prints on web page, copy it and paste in phpmyadmin, it will give you clear idea.

Comment: @number50, oh you are right. I think I found the problem. When I prints it on web page - INSERT INTO `table` (id, timestamp) VALUES (1, 2013-09-18 13:00) - The pair of quote signs are missing. That's why it can't recognise 2013-09-18 13:00 as one single string. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your query is working fine i have checked it from my end.
   Please execute the following.

$sql = "INSERT INTO `tables` (id, timestamp) VALUES (1, '2013-09-18 13:00')";

mysql_query($sql) or die("! sql");

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected the database before `mysql_query()`?

Try query using:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `db_name`.`table` (id, timestamp) VALUES (1, '2013-09-18 13:00')";      
$result = mysql_query($query, $cms2013) or die("error:".mysql_error());
```